# Color cmd window with FOR loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm try this code to make my life easier at work but I got stock. 
Hope somebody could help.

The code saves the date and time, saves the ping but when it gets to the for loop, the cmd throws me out.

```
@echo off 
:ping1
Title SAVES?
ECHO %date% - %time%
DATE /t > check_ping.txt
TIME /t >> check_ping.txt

ping -n 4 10.0.0.1

ping -n 4 10.0.0.1 >> check_ping.txt


for /f "Delims=Received ", %%a in (check_ping.txt) do (
  set TEST=%%a
)

if &TEST& > 2 goto correct
cls
color c7
echo WRONG

:correct  
cls
color 27
echo CORRECT
else

Pause 
goto ping1
```

I expected the output will color the screen according to the output of the ping. 
If I recived more then 2 it will color my screen in green, If not it wiil color my screen in red.

Comment: it's `%TEST%`, not `&TEST&`.

Comment: see `if /?` for possible comparators. `>` isn't one of them.

Comment: Another one is the syntax of [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: Several syntax errors here. Please fix them, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are still some improvements to do but here you go:

```
@echo off
:ping1
title SAVES?
echo %date% - %time%
date /t>check_ping.txt
time /t>>check_ping.txt
ping -n 4 10.0.0.1
ping -n 4 10.0.0.1>>check_ping.txt
for /f "tokens=6,7" %%a in (check_ping.txt) do (
    if "%%a"=="=" (
        if %%b GEQ 2, (
            cls
            color 27
            echo CORRECT
        ) else (
            cls
            color c7
            echo WRONG
        )
    )
)
pause
goto ping1
```

If you want to ping just once instead of twice you can replace line 7-8(and remove line 4:`echo %date% - %time%`):

```
ping -n 4 10.0.0.1
ping -n 4 10.0.0.1>>check_ping.txt
```

to something like this:

```
ping -n 4 10.0.0.1>>check_ping.txt
type check_ping.txt
ping -n 4 localhost>nul
```

This should show the ping all at once after 3 seconds(time to ping) just to be sure that the 2 pings taht you wanted to make are the same and not 2 different ones(the first one could take an avarage of 80ms and the one append to the file could be 81ms).
I also suggest to write instead of `ping -n 4 10.0.0.1` something like `ping -n 4 -l 1 10.0.0.1` where `-l 1` is how many bytes you should send to that ip to reduce network usage in case you have it slow already

Comment: sadly it doesn't help because if the ping it unreachable it still count's it in the received.

Comment: I thought of another idea: I would like to create a loop that every time TTL is received then it will sum it to me and every time I do not add 0. Can I do something like this in the BATCH file?

Comment: @ItzikBlind I don't think there is a feature like this in a batch environment, maybe you could try using powershell. I'll see anyway if there's something that can do it in batch